# Reload screen when timeout occurs

Tags: react-native

I am about to improve my first react native app and I want to show a retry/reload button when a timeout occurs. So for instance the webservice is not responding within 5 seconds I am throwing an issue. But now I want to give the opportunity to reload the screen. 
I already tried to create a refresh method and use setState, but this did not work. I think I need to start the render method once again?

```
 render() {
        if (this.state.connection === true) {
            return (
               <Login />
                    )
      else {
             <View style={styles.errorConnection}>
             <Text>Error, no Connection</Text>
             <Button title="reload" />
             </View>
            }
  }
      ...
   componentDidMount() {
        this.checkConnection();
    }

    checkConnection = async () => {
        let x = await new connection().checkConnection();
        this.setState(connection:x);
    }
```

Comment: Hey hey :) could you share your code?

Comment: I mean that button has no listener attached to it

Comment: Hi, it was more like a question how I should proceed. I just called the checkConnection and then the component is rerendering. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Mh ah, btw this code is broken it was missing a `}` after the if statement sooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask a specific question, I cannot give a specific answer but here you go. Feel free to ask in the comments :)

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        requestFailed: false,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This line is very important if you don't know why ask
        this.handleRetry = this.handleRetry.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Text>This is some very important stuff here</Text>
                {this.state.requestFailed && (
                    <Button title="Try Again" onPress={this.handleRetry}
                )}
            </>
        )
    }

    handleRetry() {
        this.fetch();
    }

    fetch() {
        fetch('your.url.url')
            .then()
            .catch(() => this.setState({requestFailed: true}))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me the line in the constructor? Is this the binding of a class object, which make it possible to use the method in the onPress without the brackets?

Comment: I think you totally got the point! See the problem is that in `handleRetry` I use another class member with `this` but `handleRetry` is going to be called from inside the button with it's `this` so the method `this.fetch` will not exist. the `.bind` method binds the so-called context and overwrites the actual context

Comment: Also if you use `<Button onPress={() => this.handleRetry()} />` this will work without any bind (as arrow functions are always bound to their parent) but this will create a new arrow function each render which hits performance slightly

Comment: Oh btw, There is an API for checking network connection. It's called [NetInfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo)